# Attribute Routing in WEB API overwrite route in Controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to add attribute routing to a ApiController like so:

```
public class PhoneNumbersController : ApiController
{
    // GET BY ID
    public PhoneNumber GetById(int id)
    {
        return PhoneNumbersSelect(id)[0];
    }

    // GET BY ID TypeOFPhoneNumbers/Id
    [Route("api/typeOfPhoneNumbers/{id}")]
    public TypeOfPhoneNumber GetTypeOfPhoneNumberById(int id)
    {
        return TypeOfPhoneNumbersSelect(id)[0];
    }
}
```

My config looks like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I'm getting a 500 Error when trying to call api/phoneNumbers/1. If I comment out the GetTypeOfPhoneNumbersId() function the default controller GetById() works fine.  What am I doing wrong? Am I not allowed to declare a unique route in the ApiController because of the way the config is set up?

Also, as I just found out, calling the api/typeOfPhoneNumbers/1 returns a 404 error, so that routing doesn't work at all.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: how are the routes configured?

Comment: I know this is old but...`[Route("~/api/typeOfPhoneNumbers/{id}")]`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you miss the controller name (phoneNumbers) in your route, this is a working code (I've tested it)

```
public class PhoneNumbersController : ApiController
{
    // GET BY ID
    [HttpGet]
    public PhoneNumber GetById(int id)
    {
        return PhoneNumbersSelect(id)[0];
    }

    // GET BY ID TypeOFPhoneNumbers/Id
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/phoneNumbers/typeOfPhoneNumbers/{id:int}")]
    public TypeOfPhoneNumber GetTypeOfPhoneNumberById(int id)
    {
        return TypeOfPhoneNumbersSelect(id)[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: I want routes like this: 
'api/phoneNumbers/1'
'api/typeOfPhoneNumbers/1'
on the same Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to access TypeOFPhoneNumbers's resource like that : ~api/typeOfPhoneNumbers?id=1